# Azure connection string does not overwrite appsettings.json

Tags: azure, azure-devops, .net-6.0, azure-configuration

I am using .NET 6.0, in the project I have appsettings.json file with the following line:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
        "SqlConnection": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=XXX;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
},
```

In Azure I have Connection Strings defined as follows:[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2cm6.png)

When I check appsettings.json in xxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/wwwroot I can see that it still uses ConnectionStrings defined in my project's appsetting.json but not in the Azure one.

My Dbcontext:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlConnection")));
```

How I get to Azure overwrite my connection string and use it instead? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The App Service will not change your appsettings.json file. It will inject any app settings (including Connection Strings) in addition to your appsettings.json file into your application (as ENV vars).

Comment: thanks, and what has precedence? looks like appsettings.json is winning?

Comment: @ShukhratRaimov https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/order-of-precedence-when-configuring-asp-net-core/

Comment: thanks for the link! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-dotnetcore-sqldb-app says that I can use in my code Configuratoin.GetConnectionString("<Connection string name from azure"), though it brings another problem of keeping the code on both on production and local files (like I would need to change back and forth after the deployment). Can you please point me the way how this can be resolved better way?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean? The name of setting can be the same in different environments, just their values should be different.